# How to access content of second and third p of same class using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I understand this might be a duplicate question but I tried looking up similar questions and I couldn't make anything work for me.

So I have a page (http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/santa-clara/global-artificial-intelligence-virtual-conference-125/speaker-details/aaron-burciaga-114059.html) from where I want to extract Topic Name, Abstract and Profile under separate lists.

I was able to get the first paragraph i.e Topic.

Can anyone help me get the abstract paragraph and profile paragraph in list.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text of the 3 parts into lists you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/santa-clara/global-artificial-intelligence-virtual-conference-125/speaker-details/aaron-burciaga-114059.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

topic = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Topic") + article')
abstract = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Abstract") + article')
profile = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Profile") + article')


topic = [t.strip() for t in topic.find_all(text=True) if t.strip()]
abstract = [t.strip() for t in abstract.find_all(text=True) if t.strip()]
profile = [t.strip() for t in profile.find_all(text=True) if t.strip()]

print("\n".join(topic), end="\n\n")
print("\n".join(abstract), end="\n\n")
print("\n".join(profile), end="\n\n")
```

Prints:

```
Practical AI: Design and Build for Adoption & Adherence

During this session, Aaron Burciaga CAP, will review the methods, critical components, emerging technology and innovative methods for designing and building artificial intelligence and maching learning systems that are “made to stick” by driving adoption and adherence principles as much with the users as with the engineers. Having developed Analytics Centers of Excellence for Fortune 100 Companies, growing and leading teams of over 400 data scientists, and being key advisor to government officials on the establishment of AI programs, Aaron will share how to deliver more “Practical AI”.
Who is this presentation for?
AI Engineers, Data Scientists, MLOps
Prerequisite knowledge:
MS, PhD, Practical experience designing and building AI systems
What you'll learn?
How to design, build, test, depoly, and manage AI systems that matter.

Aaron Burciaga is the vice president of artificial intelligence (AI) at ECS. He is responsible for building the company’s AI and machine learning (ML) capabilities and strategy and works closely with ECS’s national security and intelligence divisions to develop AI/ML solutions for ECS’ federal and commercial customers. Mr. Burciaga also leads the Analytics Center of Excellence at ECS. Prior to joining ECS, Mr. Burciaga was the global operations director for analytics and artificial intelligence at HCL Technologies. In this role, he built a high-performing global network of data scientists, AI/ML engineers, data engineers, and analysts. Together they developed strategies to revolutionize data management in order to efficiently harvest and synthesize data for quick and accurate delivery. A veteran of the Iraq War, Mr. Burciaga served as an officer in the United States Marine Corps (USMC). As a reservist, he continued to serve through 2019 as the lead data technologist at USMC headquarters, assisting the service’s chief information officer. Mr. Burciaga has a Bachelor of Science degree from United States Naval Academy and a Master of Science in Operation Research from the Naval Postgraduate School.
```

Comment: Getting this error  -  NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @SaadTufail You're using ancient version of `beautifulsoup`. Consider upgrading the module.